# Разбор логов Retrofit

Tags: android, cookie, retrofit2

Я использую Retrofit2 + OkHttpClient + HttpLoggingInterceptor :

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                 // to send multiple requests in one session
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(new CookieManager()))                 
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(basePartofAddress))
                .client(client)
                 // Converter for JSON to POJO mapping.
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
                 // this tells Retrofit that we want to use RxJava2
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) 
                .build();
```

И в логах, автоматически построенных HttpLoggingInterceptor-ом, я вижу следующее:

> ---
>
> --> POST http://host:8081/read
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 28
>
> {"id":"FAE13980"}
>
> --> END POST (28-byte body)
>
> ---
>
> <-- 200 http://host:8081/read (253ms)
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Expires: 0
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY
>
> Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BB5773DC8E9ADAB522DA3728FDFAC734; Path=/; HttpOnly
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 119
>
> Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 08:15:48 GMT
>
> {"links":{"self":"http://host:8081/auth"},"id":"FAE13980","commandRq":["50"]}
>
> <-- END HTTP (119-byte body)
>
> ---
>
> --> POST http://host:8081/auth
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 79
>
> {"id":"FAE13980","commandRs":["60"]}
>
> --> END POST (79-byte body)
>
> ---
>
> <-- 200 http://host:8081/auth (94ms)

Правильно ли я понимаю, что сервер в ответ на первый запрос телефона шлёт куки, содержащие идентификатор сессии, а телефон в следующем запросе должен (по логике?) их же пересылать серверу, но фактически (как видно из логов?) их не шлёт?

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли добавить, что надо принимать куки

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
                .build()
```

Comment: но после изменения кода с добавлением CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL  ничего не изменилось - в логах всё равно не видно, чтобы телефон пересылал в следующем запросе куки

Comment: у вас точно Retrofit и OkHttpClient создаются один раз?

Comment: да, в методе onCreate() класса приложения (в классе, наследующемся от MultiDexApplication)